# Как передать контекст?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Допустим есть такой React-компонент, вопрос в том, как передать контекст вызова отсюда:

```
this.benefitPanel = React.createRef();
this.waveBackground = React.createRef();
this.waveBackgroundWrapper = React.createRef();
this.portfolioPanel = React.createRef();
this.animationBG = React.createRef();
```

В `this.animationElements`

Видимо из-за неправильного контекста вызова, если попробовать достать DOM элемент таким образом `console.log(this.animationElements[0].ElementNode)`, мы получим `null`

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();


    this.benefitPanel = React.createRef();
    this.waveBackground = React.createRef();
    this.waveBackgroundWrapper = React.createRef();
    this.portfolioPanel = React.createRef();
    this.animationBG = React.createRef();


    this.animationElements = [{
        name: 'benefitPanel',
        class: 'benefit-panel',
        ElementNode: this.benefitPanel.current,
      },
      {
        name: 'waveBackground',
        class: 'wave-background__item',
        ElementNode: this.waveBackground.current,
      },
      {
        name: 'waveBackgroundWrapper',
        class: 'wave-background',
        ElementNode: this.waveBackgroundWrapper.current,
      },
      {
        name: 'portfolioPanel',
        class: 'portfolio-panel',
        ElementNode: this.portfolioPanel.current,
        func: function() {
          console.log(this);
        }
      },

    ]







  }
}
```

Comment: проблема не в контексте, а скорее в неверном использовании React.createRef() и того что она возвращает. Измени пример так, чтобы он демонстрировал описанную проблему

Comment: @Grundy, нет, если я выведу console.log(this.benefitPanel.current) вне объекта this.animationElements например, то мне в консоль выдаст нужный DOM элемент

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы было видно что, где и когда ты вызываешь.

Comment: И, кстати, твой комментарий подтверждает мое предположение, что ты неверно используешь _React.createRef()_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как описано в [справке](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) значение свойства `current` становится доступно после `render`.

Так как, в приведенном коде обращение к `current` идет в конструкторе - значение свойства в этот момент - `null`, и именно это значение записывается в массив.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.ref = React.createRef();
      console.log(1, this.ref.current);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(3, this.ref.current);
    }
    render() {
      console.log(2, this.ref.current);
      return ( <div ref = {
          this.ref
        } > 1 </div>);
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( 
      <App /> ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Для решения достаточно сохранять в `ElementNode` не `current`, а само поле, например:

```
ElementNode: this.benefitPanel,
```

Тогда после `render` можно будет обратиться к current: `ElementNode.current`